# Packaging Kivy App with Buildozer for OSX not working

Tags: python, macos, kivy, buildozer

I've tried packaging a Kivy app for OSX using `buildozer` following the instructions here;
https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html

There are a few issues.  Firstly, it looks for the `Kivy.app` locally, and then downloads it if it cant find it.

Regardless if I have `Kivy.app` in `/Applications` or the local `.` dir, it still says it cant find it and tries to download it.  (Even though I'm running kivy from a pip install)

As part of the download/installation of `kivy`, it then tries also download `keka`, and this fails.  So the whole process fails.

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for osx
# Check if kivy-sdk-packager exists
# kivy-sdk-packager found at /Users/REDACTED/.buildozer/osx/platform
# check if Kivy.app exists in local dir
# Downloading Keka as dependency (to install Kivy)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   217  100   217    0     0   1394      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1391
hdiutil: attach failed - image not recognized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.33.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1020, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 237, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 250, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 172, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.check_requirements()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 104, in check_requirements
    self.ensure_kivyapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 98, in ensure_kivyapp
    self.download_kivy(kivy_app_dir, py_branch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 74, in download_kivy
    check_call(('hdiutil', 'attach', 'Keka-1.0.4-intel.dmg'), cwd=cwd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('hdiutil', 'attach', 'Keka-1.0.4-intel.dmg')' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I came across this bug from Nov 2016
https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/427

Which sounds like this issue, but then lists a host of other issues they came across!

Has anyone managed to use `buildozer` on OSX?   Is `buildozer` and / or `Kivy` not production ready yet?

Im assessing it for a multi platform project, but so far can't build anything!